# How to ignore the enablefields in an extbase 1:1 relation

Tags: typo3, extbase

Is there any way to ignore enableFields like `starttime`, `endtime`, `hidden` and `deleted` in a 1:1 relation between two Extbase Domain Objects?

My Situation: My `Foo` has a `Bar` and I can get the Bar with `Foo->getBar()`

My Problem: when Bar is disabled, the ORM won't set that property with the respective model

Even greater Problem: the property is `null`, so i have no access to the uid to fetch it manually with a BarRepository->findByUidAndIgnoreEnableFields() or so

Something like @ignoreEnableFields for the property would be perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a nice workaround as long as this is not supported:

Save the reference as integer and request it in the getter with a custom repository function that ignores the enableFields.

I set up a gist for it: https://gist.github.com/econic/7302684

Answer (score -1):

You just need to setup your repository with setIgnoreEnableFields(true), see http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_persistence_1_1_generic_1_1_typo3_query_settings.html#ada5704c87dc55f261e4c5f7487125cf6

Comment: since the property mapper doesn't use the findByUid method of the repository, the ignoreEnableFields setting is not respected here. Also this would modify the Repository. Instead, this behaviour should only be true for this very property/relation.